# How might one enable '\n' interpretation with read -p command?

Tags: bash, newline, command-prompt

The following code does not display newline after the prompt:

```
function renderOrNot {
read -n 1 -p "Press 'q' to exit or any other key to repeat rendering.\n" response

if [[ $response == "q" ]] ; then
  exit
else
  nice -19 prependRpollen.py && nice -19 template.sh && nice -19 raco pollen render *.html.p*
  renderOrNot
fi   }

nice -19 prependRpollen.py && nice -19 template.sh && nice -19 raco pollen render *.html.p*
renderOrNot
```

In order to enable backslash interpretation I had to resort to  using ***echo -e*** for displaying my prompt, like so:

```
function renderOrNot {
echo -e "Press 'q' to exit or any other key to repeat rendering.\n" 
read -n 1 response
```

Is it doable to accomplish backslash interpretation in ***read -p*** command?

Comment: Why not `read -p $'whatever\n'`?

Comment: `echo "whatever"; read -n 1 response`?

Comment: @Cyrus I don't want to use ***echo*** at all and prefer to rely solely on ***read -p*** for displaying the prompt.

Comment: The Bash *read* builtin doesn't do expansions. You either have to rely on shell expansions, or just echo/printf your prompt before reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read -p "prompt"` does not interpret escapes from the prompt string.

Although, a string literal can express control characters with escaping, if it uses the POSIX candidate ANSI-C style string syntax of: `$'I am an ANSI-C style string\nin a shell script\n'`

This type of string can be used for a Bash `read -p` prompt string as:

```sh
read -n 1 -p $'Press \'q\' to exit or any other key to repeat rendering.\n' response
```

Alternatively to an ANSI-C style string, you can add the newline directly into the string as:

```sh
read -n 1 -p "Press 'q' to exit or any other key to repeat rendering.
" response
```

Also note that `read -p` prompt, and `read -n <integer>` number of characters to read, are Bash specific features, as well as `echo -e` to have `echo` interpret escapes from string literals.

---

- [gnu.org: ANSI-C Quoting (Bash Reference Manual) §3.1.2.4 ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Comment: You don't need C-style strings for this. Simply put a literal newline inside the quoted string.